# unable to compile c using make command

Tags: c

Hello Everyone I am facing a below issue with compiling the make command for my c source file

```
vinmodule.c: In function ‘vin_routing’: 
vinmodule.c:15: error: comparison between pointer and zero character constant  [-Werror=pointer-compare]
while(tmp_str!='\0') {
               ^~
vinmodule.c:8: note: did you mean to dereference the pointer?
while(tmp_str!='\0') {
        ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Here if compile the same source code with debian 9 os it works but for above OS version getting above error. Can I know what is wrong is it like c compiler version of OS?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int
main ()
{
  char *mydata = NULL;
  char *tmp_str = NULL;
  char *string_sep = ":::";
  int k;
  char *number = NULL;
  char *type = NULL;

  mydata = "1234567890:::TEST";

  k = 0;
  tmp_str = strtok (mydata, string_sep);
  while (tmp_str != '\0')
    {
      if (k == 0)
    {
      number = strdup (tmp_str);
    }
      else if (k == 1)
    {
      type = strdup (tmp_str);
    }
      tmp_str = strtok (NULL, string_sep);
      k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That error doesn't come from make, it comes from your C compiler -- and it means exactly what it says. Note that it's a _warning_, and is only treated as an error because of `-Werror` instructing the compiler to treat warnings as errors; the compiler often adds new warnings, so any project using `-Werror` takes on itself a responsibility to update the code to correct for new warnings as they're added.

Comment: What about `while(*tmp_str != ’\0’)`? As the error states, dereference the pointer.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem. And post the input and the expected output.

Comment: You cannot compare a string in C with `while(tmp_str!="\0")` anyway. But that's not what the compiler says you did. It sees your code as `while(tmp_str!='\0')`, hence the request for the MRE. Both are wrong.

Comment: I agree, if the quoted error message and the shown code contradict, double checking the [mre] is required.

Comment: char *tmp_str = NULL;
char *string_sep = ":::";

mydata = 1234567890:::TEST

k = 0;
tmp_str = strtok(mydata, string_sep);
while(tmp_str!='\0') {
 if(k == 0) {
  destination_number = strdup(tmp_str);
 }
 else if(k == 1) {
  call_type = strdup(tmp_str);
 }
 tmp_str = strtok(NULL, string_sep);
 k++;
}

Comment: Please edit the question, to show the MRE. **Complete** means it can be copy/pasted and compiled *exactly* as it is, including library headers, `main`, everything. **Mimimal** means all irrelevant code was removed.

Comment: @WeatherVane Added code in the topic

Comment: Thank you. `while (tmp_str != '\0')` ==> `while (tmp_str != NULL)`. Function `strtok()` returns a `NULL` pointer if the string could not be tokenised further. Your `'\0'` however, isn't a pointer type but an `int` type. That is the reason for `error: comparison between pointer and zero character constant`.

Comment: `const char *string_sep = ":";` would be the proper separator. Putting three of the same separator together makes no sense whatsoever. `strtok()` considers multiple sequential separators as a single separator. (which is why you cannot use `strtok()` to parse tokens while preserving empty-fields...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is defective and when you use `-Werror` any warnings will fail the build.

1. Prefer initialized variables to separate assignment.
2. Minimize scope of variables.
3. Prefer `for` to `while`-loops when iterating through an array with an index variable.  Even, as here, you need to terminate the loop in the middle.
4. `tmp_str != '\0'` compares a pointer to a integer literal.  Use `if(tmp_str != NULL)` or as below `if(!tmp_str)`.
5. `strtok()` modifies it's input so input string `mydata` needs to be writable, i.e. `char []` not `char *` otherwise you have undefined behavior (probably a segfault).
6. Consider calling `strtok()` in one place with a conditional first argument.  This result in less code duplication.
7. For given input you can simplify the logic (k or !k; that is the question).  Or go a step further and just use `strstr()` to locate the separate and navigate to the field before or after.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// strtok searches for a set of bytes (not a string) and
// skips empty tokens so k=1 will be the TEST token.
#define SEP ":"

int main(void) {
    char mydata[] = "1234567890:::TEST";
    char *number = NULL;
    char *type = NULL;
    for(int k = 0;; k++) {
        char *tmp_str = strtok(k ? NULL : mydata, SEP);
        if(!tmp_str)
            break;
        if(k)
            type = strdup(tmp_str);
        else
            number = strdup(tmp_str);
    }
    if(number && type)
       printf("number = %s, type = %s\n", number, type);
    free(number);
    free(type);
}
```

Here is a streamlined version using `strstr()` which doesn't modify it's input:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SEP ":::"

int main(void) {
    const char *mydata = "1234567890:::TEST";
    char *sep = strstr(mydata, SEP);
    char *number = NULL;
    char *type = NULL;
    if(sep) {
        number = strndup(mydata, sep - mydata);
        type = strdup(sep + sizeof(SEP) - 1);
        printf("number = %s, type = %s\n", number, type);
    }
    free(number);
    free(type);
}
```

and example output:

```
number = 1234567890, type = TEST
```

Comment: @Fe2O2 Thanks.  Tweaked as suggested. `strtok()` is evil.

Comment: Much better.... (three of the same sep.... must have been some good eggnog `:)`

Comment: @AllanWind _Evil!!_ Not exactly... Just... um... well... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1o4s1KVJaVA `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 I haven't heard that song in a very long time.  Nice.  Foot canons?  Not reentrant, modifies it's input, returns pointers to it's input string which result in stray pointers when the input string is reallocated, skips empty tokens so you can't tell if it's field 2 or 42, segfaults on NULL (which is what it returns when not finding any tokens).

Comment: @AllanWind <rant> For all of its (currently perceived) shortcomings, the C library (and UNIX in general) seem an expression of the maxim "_Do one thing well_". I don't imagine Ritchie and Thompson were writing code intended for use by _the unwashed masses_ (ie. any 21st century _gamer_ who can download an IDE and start banging on the keyboard.) IMO, writing code shouldn't be viewed as a "consumer friendly" activity. One has to bring something to the table... </rant> Merry Christmas! `:-)`